# Android Studio gives error can't run the app

Tags: android-studio

When I open Android Studio after closing suddenly Android Studio reports an error **Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap** and the RUN button is disabled. How can I recover?

[To see error click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSwIe.png)

This Image describe the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to Lower the amount of space for Java VM heap?

Comment: Yes after that i solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i find the solution. The **gradle.properties** file contains the error. The HeapSize for configure gradle is not correct i replace the -Xmx1572m with **-Xmx1024m** and close the android project and open it again and sync it, rebuild it.